# Open sets in wedge product

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces, and consider their wedge product $X\vee Y:=X \sqcup Y/\sim$ where we identify fixed points together, say $p$ in $X$ and $q$ in $Y$.

My question: Why isn't the set $X$ open in $X\vee Y$? If we let $q$ be the quotient map from $X\sqcup Y$ to $X\vee Y$, then wouldn't $q^{-1}(X)=X$, which is open i nthe disjoint union? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f^{-1}(U)$ being open doesn't in general imply anything about $U$ for continuous $f$. Also, you miscalculated $q^{-1}(X)$. It is not $X$, but $X\cup \{q\}$ (using the same letter for the quotient map and a point of $Y$ is not a good idea in general). This is usually *not* an open subset of the disjoint union.

Note that if $q$ is an open point of $Y$, then $X$ is indeed an open subset of the wedge.

Comment: Ah yes. But still, I am not sure why $X$ is not open in the wedge product.

Comment: @confusedmath I added some more details.